# Why doesn't this HTML download attribute function?

Tags: html, download, anchor, gif

I am currently working on a project and I want to download a gif sourced from the giphy API when a button is clicked. After much research I have the below code but it doesn't work and I am completely at a loss...

```
<a href="https://media0.giphy.com/media/xT5LMHMVvWbyDAtYQ0/giphy.gif" download="Downloaded.gif"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Download</button></a>
```

I suspect it has something to do with the href.

Comment: Are you saying you want the to open a "Save As/Open" dialog when clicking the link/button?

Comment: Could this be a cross-server issue? Are you trying to download the image from a different server? Maybe the source server does something to prevent the download.